# How to get correct CSS file address in my view using base_url() CodeIgniter method

Tags: css, codeigniter, directory-structure, base-url

I am developing a project in CodeIgniter but facing the following problem:

I have following codes inside my view file(header):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("includes/custom/css/slider-settings.css"); ?>">
```

On localhost it generates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/radiant/includes/custom/css/slider-settings.css">
```

There is no problem when running on localhost every css & js files being loaded perfectly. But When I upload it to live server(**to a subdomain of an existing website**) no file is getting included there. I have been trying to solve it all the way possible but couldn't.

My directory structure is

```
Radiant// root of CI
      - application
      - system
      - includes
        ----- custom
              ------css
                   ----navbar-setting.css
                   ----sidebar-setting.css
              ------js
              ------common
```

In localhost there is no problem but when uploaded to a subdomain, no file is being included.

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check http or https,  change .htaccess according to this

Answer (score 4):

OK well let me explain. this is your css href `"http://127.0.0.1/radiant/includes/custom/css/slider-settings.css"`

In here this path `includes/custom/css/slider-settings.css` is the absolute path of your CSS file. So as you have added in file structure there is no issue on the path. And this is `http://127.0.0.1/radiant/` base url defined path.

So when we came to `base_url` it will be various from one to another. It means what you set in `config.php` `base_url()` it will echo the value where ever you called.

All the time we use base URL as our project root folder. You mentioned on the question  ***to a subdomain of an existing website***. It means in `config.php` baseurl should look like this(look at second one)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'; # root folder of the host
$config['base_url'] = 'http://chat.stackoverflow.com/'; subdomained pointed URL
```