# External css file not loading in Codeigniter view

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have used css w/ codeigniter plenty of times in the past but I am just not able to configure it on a new server setup. I have looked at almost all the answers on Stack overflow but none of them seem to be working for me. I have created a very basic set of files for testing -

Controller (codeigniter/application/controllers/Pages.php)

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller{

        public function testthis(){

                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->view('testcss2');

        }
}
?>
```

View (codeigniter/application/views/testcss2.php)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSS styled page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?
>testcss.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Main content -->
<h1>Testing CSS styled page for codeigniter</h1>

<p>Welcome to my styled page!

<p>CSS Styled page

<address>7th July 2017
</address>

</body>
</html>
```

Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

The testcss.css file was placed in the root html folder on Ubuntu but I ended up copying it in almost every directory out of frustration of it not getting picked up.

The result - 
The page gets displayed successfully but without any styling. If I copy the contents of the css file and paste it in the view file inline using the style tag, the css works ! But not while using external css.

Why is using css with codeigniter so frustrating !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get correct CSS file address in my view using base\_url() CodeIgniter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996743/how-to-get-correct-css-file-address-in-my-view-using-base-url-codeigniter-meth)

Comment: Create a separate assets folder outside the codeigniter application folder. Put your CSS and JA, as well as images in it and address everything from there.

Comment: are you sure your $config['base_url']  is correct?

Comment: @Brad I tried doing that and it still wont work.

Comment: There is no problem using CSS with Codeigniter. Here is the link I use to an assets file outside the application folder "<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/main.min.css');?>" media="screen">"

Comment: Do you have another folder after localhost? "$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';" Should it be "$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/FOLDERNAME'; ?

Comment: Sorry, I see now you solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example your project name is "ProjectName",
Add folder assets and place css file inside of it.

Here in config change base_url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ProjectName/';
```

After that in view use this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/testcss.css');?>">
```

I hope it will work for you.

If feel any issue please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. What I did was re-install a fresh 3.1.5 codeigniter and loaded everything from the top. It worked. I still do not know what I did wrong the first time. Probably something wrong in the configuration.

Comment: It's part of programming. :) No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers/pages.php

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

$this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index() {    
$this->load->view('testcss');
}
}
?>
```

views/testcss.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Load css and javascript file in codeigniter</title>

<!--Load style.css file, which store in css folder.-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
</html>
```

Sometimes, you need to give permissions to use css and js from root. Putting them into folder gives you way to manage and include all from same path.